# Info from javascript text?

Tags: c#

im trying to get some information from a website (http://wowhead.com) now most if it is easy enough with html agility pack, but im stuck on how to get information after a java script tag.

The source what im trying to get info from is

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
Markup.printHtml("[ul][li]Level: 49[/li][li]Requires level 47[/li][li]Loremaster:         [url=/achievement=4931]Felwood[/url][/li][li]Side: [span class=icon-horde]Horde[/span][/li]    [li][icon name=quest_start]Start: [url=/npc=48127]Darla Drilldozer[/url][/icon][/li][li]    [icon name=quest_end]End: [url=/npc=48127]Darla Drilldozer[/url][/icon][/li]    [li]Sharable[/li][li]Difficulty: [color=r2]47[/color][small] &nbsp;[/small][color=r3]52[/color][small] &nbsp;[/small][color=r4]59[/color][/li][li]Added in patch 4.0.3[/li][/ul]", "sdhafcuvh0", { allow: Markup.CLASS_STAFF, dbpage: true });
//]]></script>
```

Now from all that, the only thing im interested in is the info from

```
[url=/npc=48127]Darla Drilldozer[/url]
```

From which i only want do display 48127 and Darla Drilldozer.

Is there anyway to do this?

Here is an example of my current code in a console to show what kind of thing im after

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Enter the Quest ID and set it as a WoWHead link
        Console.WriteLine("Enter quest ID");
        string ID = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Gathering Quest information from: http://www.wowhead.com/quest=" + ID);

        //Load WoWHead and search for the quest name in <h1>
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://wowhead.com/quest=" + ID);
        HtmlNodeCollection Qname = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1");

        //Set QuestName as the second <h1> tag
        string QuestName = (Qname[1].InnerText);

        //Display information recivied
        Console.WriteLine("Quest ID: " + ID);
        Console.WriteLine("Quest Name: " + QuestName);
        Console.WriteLine("Quest Giver: " );
        Console.WriteLine("Quest Giver ID: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

So the information needed for Quest giver and Quest giver ID are from the above Javascript.

Is there any way to get this information?

Comment: +1 Hooray for an SO question about WoW!  I think you could make this simpler with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin a cat, and one of them in this case, is to find the position of the word you are looking for and use a simple string.substring. would that work for you?

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Im not sure, as im new to C# im using this as a project to learn at this is just a something im stuck on (Dont worry the console app aint my project :p) Is there any tutorials that will explain it better for me?